# Correctly defining an application in a set of permutations

Tags: probability-theory, permutations

Let $S_n$ be the set of permutations of $[n]$.

How to define correctly a function $f:\ S_n \rightarrow S_{n-1}$ which deletes $n$? Is it implicitly clear?

Thank you

Comment: How do you expect it to be for $n=4$?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path For instance, if I have $(1, 4, 2, 3)$, the functions returns $(1, 2, 3).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you could define $f$ as follows.

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. If $\sigma$ fixes $n$, i.e. $\sigma(n)=n$. Then we define $f(\sigma)=\sigma|_{[n-1]}$ as the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\{1,\dots,n-1\}$. Otherwise $\sigma(k)=n$ for some $k<n$. We define the permutation $f(\sigma)=\sigma'$ by removing the value $n$ and attributing $\sigma(k+1)$ instead. Then we shift all values above. More precisely, we define $\sigma'(m)=\sigma(m)$ if $m<k$ and  $\sigma'(m)=\sigma(m+1)$ if $m\geq k$.

With this definition, the permutation 
$$
\sigma=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is mapped to
$$
f(\sigma)=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by $\sigma(k)=n$ for some $k<n$?

Comment: I mean the following thing. Let $k$ be the integer which satisfies $\sigma(k)=n$. (More precisely, $\sigma$ is a bijection therefore $k=\sigma^{-1}(n)$.) There are two options: 1) $\sigma(n)=n$ and thus $k=n$, or 2) $k\neq n$ and $\sigma(k)=n$.

Comment: Right, Thank you very much.